# mvn -version doesn't work without sudo

Tags: java, maven, ubuntu-14.04

This is the first that I see this: when I run in the terminal (ubuntu 14.04)

```
$ mvn -version
```

I get

```
Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.
  We cannot execute /usr/lib/jvm/oracle_jdk8/bin/java
```

With sudo, everything works fine. Any idea why is it required to be root to get the maven version?

Comment: What does your `$JAVA_HOME` environment variable contain?

Comment: /usr/lib/jvm/oracle_jdk8

Comment: Does that path really exist? If you try to manually run `${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java -version`, are you able to?

Comment: Interesting..it doesn't exist. The right path should be /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle. But the question why does it work with sudo?

Comment: I'm guessing `root` has a different `$JAVA_HOME` that your user. What do you get if you run `sudo echo $JAVA_HOME`?

Comment: the same as without sudo "/usr/lib/jvm/oracle_jdk8"

Comment: [Reference](http://askubuntu.com/questions/355042/error-java-home-is-not-defined-correctly-after-maven-installation)